# react-map-gl: uncaught ReferenceError: _typeof is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

Trying to work with `react-map-gl` but can't get the simplest lib example to work. As soon as I try to render the map I get this weird error in console I'm unable to understand:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _typeof is not defined
    at mr (blob:http://localhos…6-19b5d5c80288:4993)
    at blob:http://localhos…6-19b5d5c80288:6740
    at new Fn (blob:http://localhos…6-19b5d5c80288:6757)
    at new Jn (blob:http://localhos…6-19b5d5c80288:7040)
    at blob:http://localhos…6-19b5d5c80288:8992
    at blob:http://localhos…-19b5d5c80288:14153
```

Sometimes it changes to this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _typeof is not defined
    at mr (0bcc60f9-25f2-4a56-8906-ebd57645a06c:4993)
    at 0bcc60f9-25f2-4a56-8906-ebd57645a06c:6740
    at new Fn (0bcc60f9-25f2-4a56-8906-ebd57645a06c:6757)
    at new Jn (0bcc60f9-25f2-4a56-8906-ebd57645a06c:7040)
    at 0bcc60f9-25f2-4a56-8906-ebd57645a06c:8992
    at 0bcc60f9-25f2-4a56-8906-ebd57645a06c:14153
```

The map frame with mapbox logo renders but nothing else.

I'm on Rails 6 with those packages:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
  "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0-alpha",
  "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0-alpha",
  "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0-alpha",
  "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.7",
  "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
  "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
  "react": "^16.9.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
  "react-map-gl": "^5.0.10"
}
```

My code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactMapGL from 'react-map-gl';
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';

class Map extends Component {
  state = {
    viewport: {
      latitude: 20.827873989993776,
      longitude: -73.86145304236818,
      zoom: 3,
    },
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactMapGL
        mapboxApiAccessToken={[TOKEN]}
        {...this.state.viewport}
        onViewportChange={viewport => this.setState({ viewport })}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

Googled the error the whole afternoon but found nothing.

Comment: Try to set height and width to map.

Comment: @ravibagul91 thanks for your help. It gives me the map frame with mapbox logo but no map and still the same error in console. I've tryed passing the style also but nothing more happen.

Comment: Check the console, migh be the issue with `mapboxApiAccessToken`. Check network also.

Comment: Try to print `this.props` and check you are getting `mapboxApiAccessToken`.

Comment: Already tested both and it's ok

Comment: Looks like a Babel issue. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3422

Comment: @JakeWorth thanks, they say I should exclude `mapbox-gl.js` file from transpilation. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @adesurirey there are several solutions in that issue. I'd probably use `exclude: /mapbox-gl/` in your webpack config.

Comment: I can't find where to put this line in rails, I've tried babel.config.js, environement.js, none of this has effets

Comment: Ok I finally found how to but that doesn't solve my issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the related `mapbox-gl` issue commented by @JakeWorth I was able to find the solution from a well documented PR referenced in it: https://github.com/lewagon/rails-templates/pull/81

Adding the following line to `config/webpack/environment.js` prevents Babel from transpiling packages in `node_modules` which was the cause of my issue.

```
environment.loaders.delete('nodeModules');
```